# How to populate the value from inner join from sheet?

Tags: excel

Let's say I have 3 sheets in a csv file. Sheet2 is like a dependency table between Sheet1 and Sheet3. How do I populate `site` in Sheet1 from Sheet3? The expected value of `site` in Sheet1 is `aol`

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Sheet3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nested `VLOOKUP`: [vlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),Sheet3!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Works pretty much same as `INDEX/MATCH`, just a little bit shorter formula.
Keep in mind that "appid" in Sheet2 and "name" in Sheet3 must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Either nested INDEX-MATCH or nested VLOOKUP should work just fine. Here is the INDEX-MATCH version, it assumes your data is in Sheets1-3, in columns A and B.

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!B:B,MATCH(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),1),Sheet3!A:A,0),1)
```